# Modify product-list.tpl - Prestashop 1.7.6

Tags: prestashop-1.7

I use prestashop 1.76 and I downloaded a free module for extended categories. Currently the module is installed inside the central column, under the products) (See image 1)

In what I need your help, is to know if it is possible and how to do it, to move the module and that the description appears in the whole width of the page (See image 2)

I hope you can help me.

Thank you.
[imagen1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqrA1.png)
[imagen2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLryH.png)

Comment: You can try to move your module to another hook. Maybe displayFooter or displayFooterBefore ?

Comment: Ok thank you very much, I already solved it ..